# Allow very high-level questions about fundamental topics?

Tags: discussion

If a question is posed that essentially asks for the definition of some core piece of game development, such as [this one](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/100816/how-to-load-in-movable-full-models), can we answer those with a high-level description of the topic?

In the question I linked, the user simply doesn't know what skeletal animation *is*.  They don't need to know every detail about it, but they would benefit from getting an introduction to the topic.  In comments, this was accomplished by linking to tags.  That works, but can the question be answered regardless?

At time of writing, that question is in the close vote queue under too-broad.  I would agree that trying to completely cover the topic would be unanswerable.  But could that user get a brief introduction beyond simply linking to the tag description?

Answer (score 2):

We seem to allow [terminology](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) questions, generally. With some minor editing that question could be changed to "what is skeletal animation in the context of games?" or similar, and I think that would on-topic and answerable.

Comment: I keep peeking at the question without getting inspired about that edit.  While avoiding mutilating the question, anyway.